# Creating sub commands groups in Click CLI

Tags: python, python-click

Is it possible to group commands in sections with Click library in Python?

Flutter cli for instance, you have the section, Flutter SDK, Project, Tools & Devices.

[image]

Comment: Short answer seems to be by default no; searching on their issue tracker you may come across [`pallets/click#373`](https://github.com/pallets/click/issues/373) which is still an open issue, however [this comment](https://github.com/pallets/click/issues/373#issuecomment-512076155) provides an example formatter which should do what you want.

Comment: Hi @metatoaster, thanks for that, I manage to achieve my goal with the "cloup" library. If you make it an answer I will accept it

Comment: Please feel free to make it a self answer instead.